# Manipulate - Use values from list without displaying the values

Tags: manipulate

I have a set of different sensors which all have different names and corresponding sizes. I often need to choose a certain sensor and I want to choose it by its name. I then need mathematica to do some calculations based on the chosen sensor and its size.

I wrote this example:

```
A122   = 25.3;
A122B  = 25.7;
A322   = 32.9; 

Manipulate[
  SomeFunction[SensorSize],
  {{SensorSize, A122}, {A122, A122B, A322}}
]
```

which produces this output:

[image]

As you can see I get a nice GUI which lets me pick the right sensor but only by its size and not by his name. How can I achieve
to have the sensor names displayed in the `Manipulate` GUI while mathematica still knows which values correspond to a given sensor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[
 SomeFunction[SensorSize], {SensorSize, {A122 -> "A122", A122B -> "A122B", 
   A322 -> "A322"}, ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

with the effect

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

```
asso = Association[{"A122" -> 25.3, "A122B" -> 25.7, "A322" -> 32.9}];
Manipulate[
 SomeFunction[asso@SensorSize], {{SensorSize, (Keys@asso)[[1]]}, 
  Keys@asso}]
```